# Does it make sense to build a data processing pipeline using only Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, data-processing

I am building a data processing pipeline using Kafka.
The pipeline is linear with 4 stages.
The data volume is medium (will need more than one machine but not hundreds or thousands; data volume is a few tens of gigabytes)
My question: can I use only Kafka, having a pipeline stage consume from a topic and produce on another topic? Should I be using Spark or Storm and why? Of course, I prefer the simplest possible architecture. If I can do it all with Kafka, I'd prefer that. In the future I may need some additional machine learning stages and that may affect the answer. I have no strong once-only semantics, I can accept some message loss and some duplication with no problem.

Comment: You should look at [Samza](http://samza.apache.org) which basically provides a framework for achieving exactly this - DAGs on Kafka.

Comment: Samza looks good, but I need support for Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> My question: can I use only Kafka, having a pipeline stage consume from a topic and produce on another topic? Should I be using Spark or Storm and why?

Technically yes you can. If you are ready to handle the whole distributed architecture on your own. Writing your own multi-threaded producers, managing those consumers and so on. You also need to consider in terms of Scalability, performance, durability etc. And here comes the beauty of using computation engine like `Storm`, `Spark` etc. So you can simply concentrate on the core logic and leave the infrastructure be maintained by them.

For example using a combination of `Kafka` and `Storm` for your architecture, you can store terabytes of data using kafka and feed them to storm for processing. If you are familiar with storm then a sample topology can be something like this:

(`kafka-spout` consuming messages from topic) --> ( `Bolt-A` for processing the data receive through spout & feeding it to bolt B) --> (`Bolt-B` for pushing back the processed data into another kafka topic)

Using such architecture offers great deal in scalability, throughput, performance etc.Making some easy configuration changes you will be able to tune your application based on your requirements.